# SQL dividing two columns not working properly

Tags: mysql, database, division

Whenever I try dividing two tables with each other, it doesn't work. However, when I try to multiply, add or subtract them from each other it works. Since my list have plenty of books, I also want to not show all of the books that costs less than 1$ per page.

I want to divide the purchase price of a book with the pages of it, to calculate the price/page but it's not working out for me. This is what I've tried doing:

```
select purchase_price, pages, (purchase_price / pages) as pageprice
from books
where purchase_price >= pages
order by pageprice desc
```

Whenever I try do divide one purchase_price with anything, 2 for an example, I get 0 in return. However, when I try dividing pages it works fine. So what I'm having trouble with is that my purchase_price doesn't work to divide with. Under the values in my database it says that purchase_price is numeric, while pages and pageprice are integers.

Comment: On first look, I dont see any issues with your query. Give details about table structure. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE books;` and add the details to the question. Also, when you say, not working, what do you mean by that ? You need to show an example of "not working"

Comment: Does `purchase_price` contain the `$` symbol? You need to remove that before trying to do arithmetic with it.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain the cause of the issue. And, purchase_price does not contain that symbol, no.

Comment: What is the data type of purchase_price?

Comment: @wznd Please run the query I have given in first comment; and give us the result of the same. We need to see your table definition; Moreover, show us how some of the sample data in your table looks like.

Comment: Table structure?  Sample input?  Expected output?  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya The issue of the matter is that my purchase_price doesn't work to divide with. Under the values in my database it says that purchase_price is numeric, while pages and pageprice are integers.

Comment: @wznd "*my purchase_price doesn't work to divide with*" - Please let the community decide on this; but first your need to show us what we all have been asking.. table structure details and sample data.

Comment: [Works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hBEyq37MmUK9ufGBi1Jo2P/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way please:

```
select purchase_price, pages, (cast(purchase_price as decimal) / pages) as pageprice
from books
where purchase_price >= pages
order by pageprice desc
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked out really good.